# Jquery dual list box is not moving dynamically added options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-duallistbox

I have downloaded the code for dual list box moving. it is working fine with default select boxes. but i have to generate the select box with ajax. when the select box options are dynamically generated, then moving options to one select box to another is not working.

Here is the link I have downloaded the code:
https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/

Above linked demo is working fine since it has predefined select box.

but when i have created a dymanic selectbox options, then it is not moving options to one select box to another.

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Agent Move Tool</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HTTPS://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap4-duallistbox/4.0.2/bootstrap-duallistbox.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="HTTPS://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap4-duallistbox/4.0.2/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    h2,hr, .hr-parent{
        color:#188CCC;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }
    hr{
        border-top:1px solid #188CCC;
        margin-top:5px;
    }
    .btn-outline-secondary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4285F4;
        background-image: none;
        border-color: #000;
    }
    .btn-outline-secondary:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #3B71CA;
        border-color: #3B71CA; /*set the color you want here*/
    }
    option{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-left:4px;
    }
    .visibility{
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    .visibleShow{
        visibility:visible;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hr-parent">
            <img src="cigna-logo.svg" width="125px" class="img-responsive"/>
            <h2>Agent Team Move Tool</h2>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <br/>
        <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;width:100%;">
            <button type="button" id="get_teams" class="btn btn-warning">Get All Teams</button>
        </div>
        <div id="show_teams">                       
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel1">Select Team From which you want to move agents</label>
                    <select class="form-control first-team" id="sel1" name="sellist1">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusAll - 5020</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusCallGen - 5001</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusCity - 5018</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusCRM - 5003</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusFinance - 5016</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusHealth - 5017</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusMain - 5014</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusMobile - 5021</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusOutbound - 5022</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusTravel - 5015</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusUtility - 5019</option>
                        <option value="MainTeam">CumulusUWF - 5023</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel1">Select The Team to Which you want to move agents</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sellist1">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>CumulusMobile - 5021</option>
                        <option>CumulusOutbound - 5022</option>
                        <option>CumulusTravel - 5015</option>
                        <option>CumulusUtility - 5019</option>
                        <option>CumulusUWF - 5023</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="duallistbox_demo2" class="demo2" title="duallistbox_demo2">
                </select>
                <script>
                    var demo2 = $('.demo2').bootstrapDualListbox({
                        nonSelectedListLabel: '', // Heading of left side
                        selectedListLabel: '', // Heading of right side
                        preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
                        moveOnSelect: false,
                        nonSelectedFilter: '' // filtering multiple at once, use this "ion ([7-9]|[1][0-2])"
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        </div>
        <div  class="col-md-12">
            </br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Event log:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group row">    
                <label for="comment">Filename to Save As:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input>
                <button class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left:15px;" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-inline" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="comment">Select a File to Load:</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileToLoad">
                <button class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left:15px;" onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;margin-top:25px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.moveall').html(">> Move All");
            $('.move').html("> Move Selected");
            $('.removeall').html("<< Remove All");
            $('.remove').html("< Remove Selected");
            $('#show_teams').hide();
            $('#bootstrap-duallistbox-nonselected-list_duallistbox_demo2 option').hide();
            $(document).on('change',".first-team", function(){
                if(this.value=="MainTeam"){
                    $('#bootstrap-duallistbox-nonselected-list_duallistbox_demo2 option').show();
                    $('#bootstrap-duallistbox-nonselected-list_duallistbox_demo2').append('<option value="option1">Elmer Fudd - 1318</option><option value="option2">Josh Peterson - 1081</option><option value="option3">Trudy Jones - 1087</option><option value="option4">John Elway - 1312</option><option value="option5">Rick Barrows - 1082</option><option value="option6">Sammy Jackson - 1300</option><option value="option7">Demetra Moore - 1304</option><option value="option8">Angel Jolie - 1305</option><option value="option9">Johnny Knoxville - 1306</option><option value="option10">Jenna Anniston - 1301</option><option value="option11">Bradley Pitt - 1302</option><option value="option12">Bruce Willis - 1303</option><option value="option13">Steve O - 1308</option><option value="option14">Sandra Jefferson - 1080</option><option value="option15">Maria Quinteros - 1088</option><option value="option16">Owen Harvey - 1085</option><option value="option17">Bruce Wayne - 1320</option><option value="option18">Peter Parker - 1321</option><option value="option19">Steve Rogers - 1323</option><option value="option20">Annika Hamilton - 1086</option>');
                    
                    $('#comment').text("Elmer Fudd - 1318 Agent removed from Team CumulusAll - 5020 at 06/01/2023 04:03:00pm Successfully. &#10;Added to Team CumulusUWF - 5023");
                }else{
                    $('#bootstrap-duallistbox-nonselected-list_duallistbox_demo2 option').hide();
                    $('bootstrap-duallistbox-selected-list_duallistbox_demo2 option').hide();
                    $('#comment').text("");
                }
            }); 
            $('#get_teams').click(function(){
                $('#show_teams').slideDown(1000);
            });
        });
        function saveTextAsFile()
        {
            var textToSave = document.getElementById("comment").value;
            var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
            var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
            var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;
         
            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
            downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
            downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
            downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
            downloadLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
         
            downloadLink.click();
        }
         
        function destroyClickedElement(event)
        {
            document.body.removeChild(event.target);
        }
         
        function loadFileAsText()
        {
            var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
         
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
            {
                var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                document.getElementById("comment").value = textFromFileLoaded;
            };
            fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```